# avoid background color mixing android studio

Tags: android

How to avoid color mixing in background color of a child view with the background color of its parent?
First image is without any background color(although it is white by default) and the second image is with a light orange background color. The child view i.e., in light blue colored rectangle has its background changed after applying the orange(light) color on the background of its parent.

First image without background color:

[image: first image without background color]

Second image with background color:

[image: second image with background color]

below is my working code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/listHeightMin"
    android:background="@color/listBg">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/listHeightMin"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/listHeightMin"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/numberBg">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/english"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/hindi"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background color has an opacity set to it.

The opacity goes from 00 (completely transparent) to FF (no transparency).

In a Color, there are 4 values in hex code:

- opacity (here B1)
- red (here C6)
- green (here E2)
- blue (here E3)

So change e.g. `<color name="lightBlue">#B1C6E2E3</color>`

to `<color name="lightBlue">#FFC6E2E3</color>` (or `<color name="lightBlue">#C6E2E3</color>`)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your light blue rectangle has an opacity set to it. Instead of using opacity try to add solid hex colors.